# How can I customize eclipse to format 2d arrays?

Tags: java, eclipse, format

How can I prevent Eclipse (2019-12 in my case) from formatting (Ctrl+Shift+F) 2D array initializers such as the following, which keeps each row's set of values on one line while simultaneously starting each new row's intializer on a new line:

```
int[][] example = { 
                { 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4 },
                { 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2 },
                { 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4 } 
                };
```

into this jumbled mess?

```
int[][] example = {{3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4}
        };
```

I have gone through the Java formatting options (Whitespace, New Lines, Indent, etc.), trying various combinations of the available settings, but cannot seem to get it to keep the row initializers on the same line but start each new row's intializers on a new line.

Am I trying to make eclipse do something it was not designed to do?

Answer (score 1):

go to *windows/preferences/java/code style/formatter*

or enter *java formatter* in quick search

1. click *edit*
2. on the *Line Wrapping* tab
3. choose *Expressions* → *Array initializers*

Under The list you find every option eclipse has to offer to indent array initializers. In your case, drop down

1. *Indent on column*
2. *Wrap all elements, every element an a new line*